# Apache Thrift Compilation C++ Server

Tags: cmake, thrift

I am new to setting up tools. Sorry for the basic question

I installed Apache thrift and sucessfully running the tutorials in Linux.

I am trying to create and run a server. I am using CMAKE to build the make file. I just copied the CMAKELIST.txt from the tutorial folder and changed to my need.

When I run cmake,

`cmake CMakeList.txt`

I am getting the following error

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (include_directories):
  include_directories given empty-string as include directory.

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:27 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    ThriftMacros

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:38 (LINK_AGAINST_THRIFT_LIBRARY):
  Unknown CMake command "LINK_AGAINST_THRIFT_LIBRARY".
```

Can you please point me towards the right direction

Answer (score 0):

The command `LINK_AGAINST_THRIFT_LIBRARY` is defined in [`ThriftMacros.cmake`](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/baddaa8612fe70070208d30b91d820e99fb2a716/build/cmake/ThriftMacros.cmake). If you want to use this command, you would have to point your `CMakeLists.txt` to this macro file. For example, if you store the `ThriftMacros.cmake` file in a sub-folder `./cmake` in your source directory, you would have to add the following lines to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
list( APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake" )
include(ThriftMacros)
```

You can then link your target with:

```
LINK_AGAINST_THRIFT_LIBRARY(some_target thrift)
```